# Inline Conditional Map Literal in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Working on some translation / mapping functionality using Maps/JsonBuilder in Groovy.

Is is possible (without creating extra code outside of the map literal creation) .. to conditionally include/exclude certain key/value pairs ? Some thing along the lines of the following ..

```
 def someConditional = true   

 def mapResult = 
        [
           "id":123,
           "somethingElse":[],
           if(someConditional){ return ["onlyIfConditionalTrue":true]}
        ]
```

Expected results:
If someConditional if false,  only 2 key/value pairs will exist in mapResult.

If someConditional if true, all 3 key/value pairs will exist.

Note that I'm sure it could be done if I create methods / and split things up.. for to keep things concise I would want to keep things inside of the map creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can help yourself with `with`:

```
[a:1, b:2].with{
    if (false) {
        c = 1
    }
    it
}
```

With a small helper:

```
Map newMap(m=[:], Closure c) {
    m.with c
    m
}
```

E.g.:

```
def m = newMap {
    a = 1
    b = 1
    if (true) {
        c = 1
    }
    if (false) {
        d = 1
    }
}

assert m.a == 1
assert m.b == 1
assert m.c == 1
assert !m.containsKey('d')
```

Or pass an initial map:

```
newMap(a:1, b:2) {
    if (true) {
        c = 1
    }
    if (false) {
        d = 1
    }
}
```

#### edit

Since Groovy 2.5, there is an alternative for `with` called `tap`.  It
works like `with` but does not return the return value from the closure,
but the delegate.  So this can be written as:

```
[a:1, b:2].tap{
    if (false) {
        c = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially map all false conditions to a common key (e.g. `"/dev/null"`, `""`, etc) and then remove that key afterwards as part of a contract. Consider the following:

```
def condA = true   
def condB = false   
def condC = false   

def mapResult = 
[
   "id":123,
   "somethingElse":[],
   (condA ? "condA" : "") : "hello",
   (condB ? "condB" : "") : "abc",
   (condB ? "condC" : "") : "ijk",
]

// mandatory, arguably reasonable
mapResult.remove("")

assert 3 == mapResult.keySet().size()
assert 123 == mapResult["id"]
assert [] == mapResult["somethingElse"]
assert "hello" == mapResult["condA"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such syntax, the best you can do is

```
def someConditional = true   

def mapResult = [        
  "id":123,
  "somethingElse":[]
]

if (someConditional) {
  mapResult.onlyIfConditionalTrue = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Donal, without code outside of map creation it is difficult.

At least you would have to implement your own ConditionalMap, it is a little work but perfectly doable.

Each element could have it's own condition like

```
map["a"] = "A"
map["b"] = "B"
map.put("c","C", true)
map.put("d","D", { myCondition })


   etc...
```

Here an incomplete example (I did only **put**, **get**, **keySet**, **values** and **size**  to illustrate, and not typed - but you probably don't need types here?), you will probably have to implement few others (isEmpty, containsKey etc...).

```
       class ConditionalMap extends HashMap {

        /** Default condition can be a closure */
        def defaultCondition = true

        /** Put an elemtn with default condition */
        def put(key, value) {
            super.put(key, new Tuple(defaultCondition, value))
        }

        /** Put an elemetn with specific condition */
        def put(key, value, condition) {
            super.put(key, new Tuple(condition, value))
        }

        /** Get visible element only */
        def get(key) {
            def tuple = super.get(key)
            tuple[0] == true ? tuple[1] : null
        }

        /** Not part of Map , just to know the real size*/
        def int realSize() {
            super.keySet().size()
        }

        /** Includes only the "visible" elements keys */
        def Set keySet() {
            super.keySet().inject(new HashSet(),
                    { result, key
                        ->
                        def tuple = super.get(key)
                        if (tuple[0])
                            result.add(key)
                        result
                    })
        }

        /** Includes only the "visible" elements keys */
        def Collection values() {
            this.keySet().asCollection().collect({ k -> this[k] })
        }

        /** Includes only the "visible" elements keys */
        def int size() {
            this.keySet().size()
        }
    }

    /** default condition that do not accept elements */
    def map = new ConditionalMap(defaultCondition: false)

    /** condition can be a closure too */
    // def map = new ConditionalMap(defaultCondition : {-> true == false })


    map["a"] = "A"
    map["b"] = "B"
    map.put("c","C", true)
    map.put("d","D", false)

    assert map.size() == 1
    assert map.realSize() == 4

    println map["a"]
    println map["b"]
    println map["c"]
    println map["d"]

    println "size: ${map.size()}"
    println "realSize: ${map.realSize()}"
    println "keySet: ${map.keySet()}"
    println "values: ${map.values()}"

    /** end of script */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator to do this for for both maps and lists:

```
def t = true

def map = [
    a:5,
    *:(t ? [b:6] : [:])
]

println(map)
```

```
[a:5, b:6]
```

This works in v3, haven't tried in prior versions.